# Direct-Linking file hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, links

Hello I'm developing a project, and I need to know is there a file hosting which support direct links to txt, zip? I have tried some free hosting sites, but all I do is get 403 forbidden when trying to access the direct link. Thank you

Comment: why do not put the file on cloud, like Amazon S3 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any paid for web hosting provider will offer direct link downloads, **but most free web hosts won't as they gain no revenue from the traffic**.

If you just want to host files for download it's worth looking at [file sharing services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesharing) like [Bit-Torrent](http://bittorrent.com) [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com), [Sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/), [Putlocker](http://www.putlocker.com/), [Rapidshare](http://rapidshare.com/) and [Mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/).

All offer free file hosting or sharing in some form or another. These services generally divide into three categories.

- **Software client** based services like Dropbox (which uses a [freemium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) business model) and Sparkleshare (which is an open source [distributed social network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_social_network)) require the file's receiver to install software first, but maintain a connection allowing users to syncronise files with each other and collaborate on projects.
- **Web based** [freemium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium) services like Rapidshare and Mediafire allow the user to download from
  the web, but offer the option of a free slow download or paid for
  fast download.
- **[Peer to peer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_to_peer)** based services like Bit-Torrent are free and [open source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) but require the receiver to  to install software client.

*The lines between these categories are not clear cut, Sparkleshare for instance combines elements of software client and peer to peer.*

You should also read our community wiki ['How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?'](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements/)

Comment: If you put your files in a dropbox public folder they are accessible without anything to install.

Comment: @Sinan excellent point.

Comment: @Sinan yeah, accessible, but not with my script! I just get 403! This answer doesn't help me!